# (React) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'this' of undefined when using refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to refer to an input field using a ref in React, however I am receiving the error:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'this' of undefined". The ref is defined, however. Is there a reason why React is unable to find the ref in my code?

```
    export default class ContractorSignUp extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Find the text field via the React ref
    const user = ReactDOM.this.refs.emailInput.value.trim();

    // Clear form
    ReactDOM.this.refs.emailInput.value = '';
  }


  render() {

    return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>

              <input className="textinput" type="e-mail" placeholder="E-mail" ref="emailInput">
              </input>

          <button id="formsubmitbutton" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}><span>Submit</span></button>

            </form>
                                    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `ReactDOM` part:

```
// Find the text field via the React ref
const user = this.refs.emailInput.value.trim();

// Clear form
this.refs.emailInput.value = '';
```